# Some advise needed on how to setup reverse PTR on web and mail server

Tags: domain-name-system, postfix, amazon-web-services, reverse-dns

I'd appreciate some advise on how to run DNS with both httpd and mail running on the same server.

I have one server running on AWS, and i want to run both httpd and mail on it. Currently it just runs httpd, but i just installed postfix. There is one A record for the TLD, and a subdomain with www, both pointing to the 1 ip address i have.

Now i setup the reverse PTR also for that main TLD (so mydomain.com goes to 5.5.5.5, and 5.5.5.5 goes to mydomain.com). But now that i want to install postfix, i'm thinking i should change that to www.mydomain.com, as i think that would probably a wise idea if i'm going to send and receive email.

Does this make sense? Below is how i currently have it setup (i also added www.mydomain.com as a MX record, which is not shown below). Or should the A record pointing to mydomain.com always have a reverse record pointing back to that my domain.com

Thank you

Pic attached:
http://i63.tinypic.com/j0d1ef.jpg

Comment: Could you clarify how did you set your reverse DNS?

Comment: Hi AlexD, sorry didn't see your comment. You have to submit a form with AWS to set that up, as it's their ip space.

Answer (score 1):

It makes no difference what you use, as long as the A record and PTR record match each other, and there's a compelling reason to use neither of the alternatives you suggested.

> Now i setup the reverse PTR also

Because you didn't mention the standard process for setting up reverse-DNS records in AWS, I am skeptical as to whether you have done this correctly.  You don't set this up yourself.  AWS support controls reverse DNS.

Instead, you...

- allocate an Elastic IP address that you will be using with your mail server, if it isn't already using one. You can't do this with an IP from the public pool.
- decide what name you want... you should probably make this email-specific, since you're not going to be able to move this name, and you don't want to create a permanent dependency for your web site on this address, even if that's what you're using it for at the moment.   A common choice might be something like `smtp-us-west-2.example.com` where `us-west-2` is the AWS region and `example.com` is one of your domains.
- create an appropriate A-record with that name pointing to the EIP.
- log in with your root account credentials and submit [this form](https://portal.aws.amazon.com/gp/aws/html-forms-controller/contactus/ec2-email-limit-rdns-request) to AWS Support.

The form serves two purposes: it requests that they remove the default outbound port 25 rate limiting that exists for all of EC2 from your addresses, and it allows you to request that *they* create the reverse DNS PTR record for you -- they are the only ones who can do this, since it is their IP address space, not yours.  If you created a reverse DNS entry somewhere, it isn't going to actually do anything.

Comment: I'm aware of the process, i've done it for the main tld. The reason i don't want another subdomain like mail.mydomain.com, is because it would require me getting another elastic ip address, which requires me paying as it would go out of free tier. That's why i thought of combining both on the same server.

Comment: Ah, I see.  It genuinely doesn't matter, then.  As long as the records match, e.g. `200.113.0.203.in-addr.arpa PTR foo.example.com.` has a matching `foo.example.com A 203.0.113.200` then it is all good, even if the mail is for `example.org`.  The only important things are that they must be consistent with each other and `foo.example.com` must be an `A`, not a `CNAME`.

Comment: Thank you. So if i set my www.domain.com to the ip address and vice versa, i guess that leaves domain.com kind of hanging, but that's not a problem is it? would http to domain.com not work well if i do this or should it not make a difference.Also, could you critique my dns setup (see link). Much obliged.

Answer (score 0):

You likely want to add a sub-domain (hostname) like `mail.example.com` or `smtp.example.com`.  This should be the name on the PTR record as well as the name that Postfix identifies itself when connecting to other servers.  Many sites will be lenient if your rDNS validates for the sending IP address, although the name in the HELO command should also validate.

You will also want SFP records for domains involved in our mail.  It is also a good idea to add and SPF record for domains not sending email.  (Adding SPF records for non-mail involved domains like www prevents them from being used as Spam soruces.) I have posted an article on Securing your Email Reputation with SPF.  You will likely want the following SPF records (you may want to start with a `~all` policy):

```
example.com.         TXT   v=spf1 mx -all"
mail.example.com.    TXT   "v=spf1 a -all"
www.example.com.     TXT   "v=spf1 -all"
```

You should also consider DKIM which require a key record as a sub0domain of `_domainkey.example.com.  This may be required to get delivery to some destinations.

Also look at DMARC which will allow you to publish you SPF and DKIM policies.  Most sites validating DMARC will send you delivery reqports if requested. DMARC is configure using an `_dmarc` sub-domain tree.

Comment: Hey, thanks. If you look in my attachment you can see i'm using spf, dkim and dmarc. The reason why i don't want to use another subdomain is because that would require me getting another elastic ip address, and i would have to pay for that.

Comment: @AlefVeld You should be able to run all the sub-domains on one IP address. You can use a CNAME for your www sub-domain,  The name in your MX record needs have an A and/or AAAA record.