# where (and how!) to add spf record for www subdomain

Tags: domain-name-system, spf, reverse-dns

This is a followup to question: [Some advise needed on how to setup reverse PTR on web and mail server](https://serverfault.com/questions/851404/some-advise-needed-on-how-to-setup-reverse-ptr-on-web-and-mail-server/851450?noredirect=1#comment1093526_851450)

So i've decided to use my www subdomain for both www and mail. My current problem is not knowing where to put the spf record for that. I've scoured other postings on this subject but i'm still not sure. I had the original put under my maindomain.com:

```
v=spf1 a mx ip4:52.56.221.37 -all
```

But it doesnt seem to work for my www.maindomain.com (even though that's the right ip address for it). I get spf failed in my mailheaders. I use dynadot as a name registrar. There's a domain record entry and a subdomain record entry.

Do i need to change either the top record, or do i need to add a SPF record for the www.mydomain.com, under the subdomain record entries. If so, how ? Do i add
www subdomain, choose a TXT record and add the above SPF record (even though i already have a www A record subdomain)

Thank you for helping me out with this seemingly basic question.

Answer (score 1):

I think some clarification needs to take place. SPF records are for mail being sent out from you. It applies to the zone that mail is being sent from (i.e., the "domain" part of the address). If your domain is `example.com` and you're sending a message from a "normal mail client" as `joe.blow@example.com`, you would have a TXT/SPF record for `example.com`. If you're sending mail from your web server as `web.server@example.com`, that one TXT/SPF record will cover that just fine, provided the IP addressing information you specify is correct (e.g., covers your web server and your mail server). Let's say your mail server is 52.56.221.36 and your web server is 52.56.221.37. You could have two separate entries in your TXT record: `ipv4:52.56.221.36` and `ipv4:52.56.221.37` (or if you want to use CIDR, just `ipv4:52.56.221.36/31`.

You would only need a special "www" TXT/SPF record if you were sending mail from web.server@**www**.example.com. In that case, I would suggest having only one "main" TXT/SPF record, but just refer to it from your www record.

In BIND it might look like this:

```
@   IN TXT "v=spf1 a mx ip4:52.56.221.36 ip4:52.56.221.37 -all"

www IN A   52.56.221.37
www IN TXT "v=spf1 redirect=example.com"
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming remote clients would send messages to toto@example.com, then you need to set your SPF record on example.com itself, regardless of which MXs are involved.

With the names you're using in your post, you would add your SPF record for mydomain.com

Comment: Right. So i did that, but outlook (the domain i'm sending to) still flags it as spam and not a valid spf record.

Comment: Can you update your post with the received message headers (that should mention something about SPF failing, and the path your message took)? Looking at mxtoolbox.com for grabaguru.com (am I right to assume this is yours?), SPF looks fine.

Comment: Sidenote: your MX being the sole IP listed, then you could set your SPF record to `v=spf1 mx -all`